# Flutter NPE Unable to destroy activity

Tags: flutter, flutter-plugin, flutter-platform-channel

when i  exit from flutter app two times it should me this crash. previously i used plugin and removed it im wondering why it showed this function `setMethodCallHandler` and no used for it before. can any one provide guide for this. would be helpful.

```
Unable to destroy activity : java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke 

virtual method 'void io.flutter.plugin.common.MethodChannel.setMethodCallHandler(io.flutter.plugin.common.MethodChannel$MethodCallHandler)' on a null object reference
        
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void io.flutter.plugin.common.MethodChannel.setMethodCallHandler(io.flutter.plugin.common.MethodChannel$MethodCallHandler)' on a null object reference
```

Answer (score 0):

i discovered the error was in plugin that i used to check if device is rooted. for any one whose is facing this problem in flutter check the log messages and see lines after **caused by** then try to see what plugin name appeared.